# Authenticate failure for software updates. New install of Kubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, password, authentication

The system will not accept my password created at install. I have researched this error but do not understand how to proceed. The answers I get are way too technical for my knowledge. I am a first time user of linux.

Any very specific help greatly appreciated.

<<< In response to one comment:
I have triple checked the password and entered it in the GUI and in the terminal. The password is *absolutely* correct. Regarding the keyboard, it is the same one I used to install and create the password originally. If the system somehow changes the keyboard, how do I check that?

<<Response to another comment:

There are only four possibilities:

1. You typed it wrong when you installed Kubuntu. **I don't know how to check/remedy this.**
2. You're typing it wrong now. I've made multiple checks of my entries. ***Using the GUI "eyeball" I always verify my entry. I'm typing what I think is the password correctly.***
3. You're not in Kubuntu at all, but at some other prompt somewhere else.
   ***I'm viewing Kubuntu screen and using its GUI.***
4. The system is not asking for your password, but asking for something else. ***The screen response is on the Kubuntu desktop and it requests the password.***

More info--I tried changing the password with the User Manager. It responds "Authentication failure, please try again. Additional tries results in same error.

Attempts to change password with authentication error. (NB, getting same error when trying to update software)

Comment: It would be great if OP responded with current status. This could be resolved.

Comment: I would be most happy to respond with current status (SOLVED) if I knew how.